# HOWTO parse textfile for lines containing expressions of the form VARIABLE=SOMEVALUE

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have a textfile (actually, .xml) that contains certain lines of the form MACAddress=SOMEVALUE, and mixed within other lines. For example, a typical such line is (on a single line):

`<Adapter slot="3" enabled="false" MACAddress="080027671C79" cable="true" speed="0"
type="Am79C973">`

N.B. In the line above, SOMEVALUE is "080027671C79" precisely.

So, I would want to parse the file, and collect all of the SOMEVALUES.
How can I do this in python (re ?, find?) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

It's XML, so use an XML parser. For example:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

macs = [adapter.getAttribute("MACAddress") for adapter in
        parse("file.xml").getElementsByTagName("Adapter")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that i correctly know what is MAC address but please fine two more options below:

Input:

```
text = """
Adapter slot="3" enabled="false" Mcable="true" speed="0" type="Am79C973">
Adapter slot="3" enabled="false" MACAddress="080027671C79" cable="true" speed="0" type="Am79C973">
Adapter slot="3" enabled="false" MACAddress="080027671C71" cable="true" speed="2" type="Am79C973">
Adapter slot="3" enabled="false" MACAddress="080024671C79" cable="true" speed="1" type="Am79C973">
Adapter slot="3" enabled="false" MACAddress="080227671C79" cable="true" speed="1" type="Am79C973">
"""
```

1) RegEx:

```
from re import findall
findall(r'(?i)(?<=MACAddress=\")\w{12}', text)
```

2) String slicing:

```
searchTxt = 'MACAddress="'
searchLen = len(searchTxt)
getMAC = lambda line: line[line.index(searchTxt) + searchLen: line.index(searchTxt) + searchLen + 12]
map(lambda line: getMAC(line), (line for line in text.split() if searchTxt in line))
```

Comment: @Artsiom Rudzenka What does the **(?i)** part, please ?

Comment: @eyquem - ignore case - e.g. case insensetive

Comment: @Artsiom Rudzenka Thank you. Are you sure it is a functionnality available in Python ? It seems to me it exists in other language but not in Python. Never seen. Have you a reference to give, please ? In Python, to ignore case : **re.compile(pattern, re.IGNORECASE)**

Comment: @eyquem as per python tutorial: "(?iLmsux) - (One or more letters from the set 'i', 'L', 'm', 's', 'u', 'x'.) The group matches the empty string; the letters set the corresponding flags: re.I (ignore case), re.L (locale dependent), re.M (multi-line), re.S (dot matches all), re.U (Unicode dependent), and re.X (verbose), for the entire regular expression. (The flags are described in Module Contents.) This is useful if you wish to include the flags as part of the regular expression, instead of passing a flag argument to the re.compile() function."

Comment: @Artsiom Rudzenka Oh I saw this once and I forgot it. I will use it to shorten some patterns. Thank you !

Comment: @eyquem you are welcome, glad to be helpful. By the way you can try to use RegExBuddy - it seems a very helpful to me on a road of python regex learning.

Answer (score 0):

A regex will be the faster tool.

The one of Artsiom is too restrictive, I think. I would do:

```
from re import findall
findall('MACAddress=([^ \t]+)', text)
```

But I think you want what is BETWEEN the quotes **"**   . Then:

```
from re import findall
findall('MACAddress="([^"]+)"', text)
```

.

Is it possible that the SOMEVALUE you want to catch contain quotes **"** ?